# CSV File Loop Only Loops Once

Tags: python, loops

The script does essentially what I want it to do but it only produces one file. The goal is for the file to read all the links in one column, download each file, rename it to names in the names in a different column and add .jpeg exstention to each one

```
import csv
import urllib.request
import openpyxl
import shutil, os
with open("C:\\OB\\827.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for column in reader:
     fileurl = column[12]
     filename = column[9]
    test = urllib.request.urlretrieve(fileurl, "C:\\OB\\" + filename +".jpeg")
    print(test)
```

> ('C:\OB\Brian Weeks.jpeg', )

I get the file I actually want but just 1 of 12 or so. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your code indent is not ok I guess

Comment: Your variable name is not good. The `column` variable actually holds rows.

Comment: Indent the `test =` and `print` lines so they're in the loop.

Comment: This is just a typo: Python cares about indentation, since `test = ..` and `print` are indented less than the previous lines, they are outside your `for` loop. Use consistent indents (4 spaces is standard) and the problem would be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test` should be within the loop

Comment: everything seems to be working but it is only printing the last line in the column

Comment: well, `print` should be within the loop as well.. xD